# Datalist hint/autocomplete showing properly only on Firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

I have a simple code like:

```
<input list="list1" type="text"></input>
<datalist id="list1">
<option value="one"></option>
<option value="two"></option>
<option value="three"></option>
</datalist>
```

It is showing hint properly on Firefox, but not working at all on Chrome, Opera, etc.

What's the problem, how can I solve it?

Comment: What type of hint are you referring to?

Comment: Here's a compability chart for `datalist` http://caniuse.com/#search=datalist

Comment: @Robin Dorbell hint fit to the typed letters

Comment: @user6769169 see below demo it is work on Chrome, Opera, but nothing much changes between your code and this demo.   

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akZQqa

Comment: @Thasneen it does NOT work on opera, chrome, tec - if U type f.e. 'script' it wont show U 'Javascript' (and it FF it will) - that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

### Alternative 1

The hint if shown in the latest version of all major browser except safari. For a complete compability list see: http://caniuse.com/#search=datalist

```
<input list="list1" type="text" />
<datalist id="list1">
    <option value="one"></option>
    <option value="two"></option>
    <option value="three"></option>
</datalist>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7zegkerb/

### Alternative 2

Using jQuery AutoComplete you can produce this functionality across all browsers.

```
var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];

$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w2yLpneo/

Comment: but it is not working on a new chrome and opera the way it does on FF. What I mean is that when I type sth in given input on FF, f.e. 'set' - it shows me only the options with given word. But on chrome, opera, ie etc - it does not work. Is there a way to solve this or any alternative?

Comment: It should be working. It's working for me in newest chrome. You could also do your own javascript solution or use the jQuery AutoComplete

Comment: the problem is that it seems that FF searches for any string in option, f.e. if I type 'script' - it will give me an option 'javascript'. And in Chrome, opera etc - it wont (it will only give me 'javascript' if I start typing from the first letter). Thats is my problem I believe.

Comment: Ok. That's just the way it's implemented by the browser then - nothing you can do to change it. You could try the other solution, it's highly customizable.

Comment: ok, I'm trying the jQuery solution but it's not working and I dont know why. I'm putting the div in body, and the jvascript beneath - but does not show any hint

Comment: I also dont see there any css ?

Comment: You need to include the libraries. That's also where the CSS comes from. Use this link to the documentation https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/.